How are heat capacities of substances measured?
To summarise Wikipedia: take substance at known temperature, add known amount of heat energy to it and measure the change in its temperature. But how do we add a known amount of heat energy?

See Calorimeter

Place an electric heater element inside the substance. Insulate the substance from its surrounding as best as you can (still air is a pretty good thermal insulator). Calculate the power from $P = UI$ where $U$ is voltage and $I$ is current. Multiply by the time the heater is on to find the heat transferred.

You could put your substance at a specified temperature into contact with a reference substance (e.g., water) at a different temperature and allow them to equilibrate.  If you know the heat capacity of the reference substance, then you know how much heat was transferred, and you can calculate the heat capacity of your substance.

Specific heat capacity can be determined by Differential Scanning Calorimetry. A standardized test for making the determination is ASTM E1269.
The benefit of using a single standardized test is one can compare the results for different materials under the exact same test conditions that have been determined to be repeatable and reproducible.
Hope this helps.
